# How to send video stream to node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, video

My goal: send some video stream from one client to another throught node.js server. But I can`t even send video from first cleint to server.

Cleint

```
var socket = io(":9966");

    socket.on('message', function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    })

    function onVideoFail(e) {
        console.log('webcam fail!', e);
    };


    window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    navigator.getUserMedia  = navigator.getUserMedia ||
        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
        navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
        navigator.msGetUserMedia;

    var video = document.querySelector('video');


        navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, function(stream) {
            console.log(stream);
            video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);

            var arrayOfStreams = [stream];
            var medias = new MediaStreamRecorder(stream);
            medias.ondataavailable = function(blob) {
                socket.emit("streaming", blob);
            };
            medias.start();
            socket.emit("streaming", stream);
            socket.emit('test', 'mess from 1');
        }, onVideoFail);
```

Server

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
log.info('new con!', socket.id);

socket.send("you connected to server");

socket.on('test', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.broadcast.send(data);
});

socket.on('streaming', function (stream) {
    log.info("i`m in stream", socket.id);
    log.info(stream);

    socket.broadcast.emit('streaming', stream);
});
});
```

I can send text and everything great, but when I send stream to server I get empty value.

[What I see on server side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sm5bM.png)

I looked for some tips and found, but still not working. Maybe I missed something.

Can anyone help me?

PS I getting video from video tag

Answer (score 0):

convert your media to base64, this way the server reads it as a string of texts and returns it back

Comment: I red about base64 and it works only for image. Is this correct?

Answer (score -2):

Question is closed. As I red its hard to make live stream. If somebody reading this, check this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder . What you must understand: record little part of video and send it to server. Hope it`s will help.